# Spreadtable bug \ST@after@ref@found

Tags: bugs, spreadtab

Tried to compile an old, once working document, but a bug popped out.
Took an example from the documentation, but the bug showed up. I use TexLive2023, I update it regularly

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ccccc}}
1 & & & & \\
a1 & a1 & & & \\
a2 & a2+b2 & b2 & & \\
a3 & a3+b3 & b3+c3 & c3 & \\
a2 & a4+b4 & b4+c4 & c4+d4 & d4
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}


New spreadtab: \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
* reading tab:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ST@after@ref@found 
                    
l.13 \end{spreadtab}
                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: It looks as if the author of spreadtab (Christian Tellechea) should communicate better with the author of xstring (Christian Tellechea).  spreadtab uses an internal command of xstring (`\@xs@afterinteger`) which no longer exists in the newest xstring.  Make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Where can I report it? Github, I couldn't find any?

Comment: open the documentation and look for a clue.

Comment: email? badly, but, uh.

Comment: well there is an update announced, so it looks as if the problem should be gone tomorrow.